# How to Calculate FRR & FAR scores using R

Tags: r, artificial-intelligence, classification, analytics, metrics

I am currently trying to calculate the FAR & FRR of my model. However, I can't seem to find a way to do this. I have managed to calculate the Precision, Recall & Accuracy using the MLmetrics library but no luck for the FAR & FRR.

Below is a snippet of what I am currently using to calculate the metrics mentioned above.

```
dataPredict <- predict(dataModel, dataTest)

Precision(dataPredict, dataTest$Type)
Recall(dataPredict, dataTest$Type)
Accuracy(dataPredict, dataTest$Type)
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.